# How to serve Blazor web assembly on the path of an ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I want serve Blazor Web Assembly into a path in the ASP.NET Core MVC app
like this.

this is ASP.NET Core MVC: `example.com`

and my blazor app run on this path: `example.com/admin`

Comment: You simply haven't given enough information to provide a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

First add the service:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

Then add pipeline:

```
app.MapBlazorHub();
```

Create a folder `Components` as an example and add `.razor` file.

You can check out : [Using Blazor in Your Existing ASP.Net Core MVC Applications](https://medium.com/capgemini-microsoft-team/using-blazor-in-your-existing-asp-net-core-mvc-applications-f1b09bd66f4b) which is a good starting point.